# Proof $X_n/a_n \rightarrow 0$ given $\sum_{i=1}^{n}X_i/a_n \rightarrow 0$ (in probability)

Tags: probability, probability-theory

I’m trying to solve the following problem: Given a sequence $(a_n)$ of positive real numbers such that $\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}=1$ (could be $a_n=n$ for example) and a sequence of random variables $X_n$, I need to prove that if $(\sum_{i=1}^{n}X_i)/a_n \rightarrow 0$ in probability then $X_n/a_n \rightarrow 0$ also in probability.

I tried to bound $|X_n/a_n|$ by $\sum_{i=1}^{n}|X_i|/a_n$ to apply the definition of convergence in probability, but since the $X_n$ might not be positive this doesn’t work. I also tried using the definition of a Cauchy sequence in probability to prove $X_n/a_n$ is also Cauchy but I got a mess that doesn’t seem to arrive to anything. Finally I tried to extract a subsequence that converges almost surely but again I don’t seem to get anything useful.

Could you give me any hint?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $Y_n:= a_n^{-1}\sum_{i=1}^nX_i$. Then by assumption, $Y_n\to 0$ in probability and it follows that $Y_{n+1}\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}-Y_n\to 0$ in probability (using $a_{n+1}/a_n\to 1$), which gives the wanted conclusion.